# Android Studio: package android.support.annotation does not exist

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, appcompatactivity

Before to write here, maybe I read all similar questions in Stackoverflow and others webpages... and I cannot find the solution...please, can you help me?
I have these errors:

Package android.suppoort.annotation does not exist:

•   Error: import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

Package android.support.v7.app does not exist

•   Error: import.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

Cannot find symbol class AppCompatActivity:

•   Error: public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

I have the last version of Android Studio 3.6.3.

My build.gradle(module :app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "codingwithmitch.com.forsale"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    } 
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"


    //Design Support library dependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    //recyclerview
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    //ExifInterface support
    implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0"

    //Universal image loader
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

    //retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'

    //retrofit gson lib
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    /*
        ---------- Firebase -----------
     */

    //Firebase Authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'

    //Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'

    //Firebase Storage
    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'


    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0"
    annotationProcessor 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Build.gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        //maven {
            //url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        //}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle.propierties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```